# Completing future with TimeoutException or Awaiting?

Tags: scala, future

I have the following trait:

```
trait Tr{
     /**
      * Returns future of the number of bytes written
      */
     def write(bytes: Array[Byte]): Future[Long]
}
```

So I can await the result like this:

***I.***

```
val bts: Array[Byte] = //...
val to: Long = //...
val tr: Tr = //...
Await.result(tr.write(bts), to)
```

But I also can design the `Tr` in a bit different way:

```
trait Tr{
     /**
      * Returns future of the number of bytes written
      */
     def write(bytes: Array[Byte], timeout: Long): Future[Long]
}
```

***II.***

```
val bts: Array[Byte] = //...
val to: Long = //...
val tr: Tr = //...
Await.result(tr.write(bts, to), Duration.Inf)
```

What is the better way? I think the ***II*** case has its use in case where the actual writing-IO is not interruptible or performed by a caller thread. So for flexibility I would design the thread in the ***II*** way.

The thing is writing forever in ***II*** looks a bit wierd.

Is it correct to do so? Or I'm abuse the `Future`?

Upd: Consider the following possible implementation of the `Tr`:

```
class SameThreadExecutionContext extends ExecutionContext{
  override def execute(runnable: Runnable): Unit = runnable.run()
  override def reportFailure(cause: Throwable): Unit = ???
}

clas DummyTrImpl extends Tr{
    private final implicit val ec = new SameThreadExecutionContext
    override def write(bytes: Array[Byte]): Future[Long] = {
         Thread.sleep(10000)
         throw new RuntimeException("failed")
    }
}
```

Now if I write this:

```
val bts: Array[Byte] = //...
val to: Long = 1000
val tr: Tr = new DummyTrImpl
Await.result(tr.write(bts), to) //Waiting 10 secs instead of 1 
                                //and throwing RuntimeException instead of timeout
```

Comment: Can you please provide some more clarification on the question. It is not clear

Comment: @ChaitanyaWaikar Done!

Comment: Using ```Await``` is known as a bad pratice since you're blocking a thread from the dedicated threads pool. If you don't need a future, don't use it !

Comment: @alifirat Blocking a thread on waiting is not an issue in my case, but I would like to wait at most...

Comment: @alifirat Moreover wait-free implelemnation is gonna be kind of complicated...

Comment: @SomeName The first implementation seems to be better than the 2nd one because it does not break the contract of future.

Comment: @ChaitanyaWaikar But what contract does the 2nd break?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Option II is generally preferred (or globally set timeouts), because Futures are not generally "awaited", but tend to be chained instead.

It is unusual to write code like:

```
Await.result(tr.write(bts, to))
```

and more common to write code like:

```
tr.write(bts, to).then(written => ... /* write succeeded, do next action */ ..)
```

Answer (score 2):

The two traits have different behaviours, so it depends a little on what you are trying to achieve.

Trait ***I.*** says

> Write some data and take as long as necessary. Complete the `Future` when the write completes or fails.

Trait ***II.*** says

> Try to write some data but give up if it takes too long. Complete the `Future` when the write completes, or fails, or times out

The second option is preferred because it is guaranteed to progress, and because the `write` is not left hanging if the `Await.result` times out.